# How to get text/val from a list of things using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have customized the wp_get_archive added a class="tlyear" to its  tag.

and using jquery to get each of the years

```
var y = jQuery('.tlyear');
var m = jQuery('.tlyear').text();
jQuery('.tlyear').click(function() {
  alert(m);
});
```

when I click on one of the  it supposes to return the alert text as 1955 but instead, it returns me a whole string of years as "19481955". How do I get the years only from the  I click on? since all the  has the same class.

[image]

Comment: `$(this).text().trim()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to get the text of the just the clicked item, so make use of `this`, which refers to that item:

```js
jQuery('.tlyear').click(function() {
    alert(jQuery(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tlyear"><a href="#">1948</a></div>
<div class="tlyear"><a href="#">1955</a></div>
<div class="tlyear"><a href="#">1963</a></div>
```

(Or it may make sense to use `jQuery(this).find('a').text()`, because you're binding the click handlers to the containing divs, not to the anchor elements that have the text you want, though it doesn't really matter if there are no other elements within those divs.)

In your code, this line:

```
var m = jQuery('.tlyear').text();
```

...gets the text of *all* of the matching elements with no relation to which one(s) might later be clicked on.

Comment: after i change to alert($(this).text()); it doesnt work the alert box did not appear.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention that you were using `jQuery` rather than `$`. Try `jQuery(this).text()` and that should do it as per the demo I just added to my answer.

Comment: Oh ya thanks i ownself forgot about it too jQuery haha. thanks it work now